# Get input/output type of callable

Tags: c++, c++14, callable, template-argument-deduction

I have the following problem:

```
template<typename Func, typename T_in = /*input type of Func */, typename T_out = /*output type of Func */>
std::vector<T_out> foo( Func f, const std::vector<T_in>& input)
{
  std::vector<T_out> res( input.size() );

  for( size_t i = 0 ; i < input.size() ; ++i )
    res[ i ] = f( input[ i ] );

  return res;
}


int main()
{
  // example for f(x) = x*x
  std::vector<float> input = { /* ... */ };
  auto res = foo( [](float in){ return in*in; }, input );

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see above, I try to implement a function `foo` which maps a function `f` to each element of an input vector `input`. My problem is the following: I want the elements of the input vector `input` to have the input type of `f` (i.e., `T_in`) and the elements of the output vector the output type of `f` (i.e., `T_out`) but without passing the input/output type of `f` explicitly to `foo` (due to a better readability of the code). Has anyone an idea how the input/output type of `f` can be deduced automatically at compile time?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `T_in` can be deduced from the `input` vector.

I think that the deduction of `T_out` is a work for `std::result_of_t`

```
template <typename Func, typename T_in,
          typename T_out = std::result_of_t<Func(T_in)>>
std::vector<T_out> foo( Func f, const std::vector<T_in>& input)
{
  std::vector<T_out> res( input.size() );

  for( size_t i = 0 ; i < input.size() ; ++i )
    res[ i ] = f( input[ i ] );

  return res;
}
```

Using `typename std::result_of<Func(T_in)>::type` instead of `std::result_of_t<Func(T_in)>` should work also for C++11, not only for C++14.

Answer (score 2):

`decltype` would work for this, along with changing `foo`'s return type to `auto`.

```
template<typename Func, typename T_in>
auto foo( Func f, const std::vector<T_in>& input)
{
  std::vector<decltype(f(input[0]))> res( input.size() );

  for( size_t i = 0 ; i < input.size() ; ++i )
    res[ i ] = f( input[ i ] );

  return res;
}


int main()
{
  // example for f(x) = x*x
  std::vector<float> input = { /* ... */ };
  auto res = foo( [](float in){ return in*in; }, input );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a map of functions it actually very common design pattern is c++. i recommend you using std::Map container for this. [here is a link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

good luck :)

Comment: Thank you. For simplicity, I used a simplified example in my post above. Unfortunately, my real example can't be implemented by using the standard library.