# Get input/output type of callable within a class definition

Tags: c++, c++14, callable, template-argument-deduction

I have the following problem:

```
template< typename Func >
class A
{
  public:
    A( Func f ) : _f( f ) {}

    // ...

    template< typename T_in = /*input type of _f */, typename T_out = /*output type of _f */ >
    std::vector<T_out> operator()( const std::vector<T_in>& input)
    {
      std::vector<T_out> res( input.size() );

      for( size_t i = 0 ; i < input.size() ; ++i )
        res[ i ] = _f( input[ i ] );

      return res;
    }

  private:
    Func _f;
    // ...

};

template< typename Func >
A<Func> A_wrapper( Func f )
{
  return A<Func>( f );
}

int main()
{
  // example for f(x) = x*x
  std::vector<float> input = { /* ... */ };

  auto f          = []( float in ){ return in*in; };
  auto map_square = A_wrapper( f );

  auto res = map_square( input );

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see above, I try to implement a class `A` whose function `operator()` maps a function `_f` to each element of an input vector `input`.

My problem is the following: I want the elements of the input vector `input` to have the input type of `_f` (i.e., `T_in`) and the elements of the output vector the output type of `_f` (i.e., `T_out`) but without passing the input/output type of `_f` explicitly to the class `A`, the function `A_wrapper` which I use for type deduction and/or the function `operator()` (due to a better readability of the code).
Has anyone an idea how the input/output type of `_f` can be deduced automatically at compile time?

Many thanks in advance.

BTW: The question here is related to my previous post [Get input/output type of callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108966/get-input-output-type-of-callable/40109446#40109446)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda) looks like what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108966/get-input-output-type-of-callable), [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108966/get-input-output-type-of-callable/40109446#40109446): you can deduce `T_in` from the `input` vector and `T_out` using `std::result_of_t`

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template< typename Func >
class A
{
  public:
    A( Func f ) : _f( f ) {}

    // ...

    template< typename T_in,
              typename T_out = std::result_of_t<Func(T_in)>>
    std::vector<T_out> operator()( const std::vector<T_in> & input)
    {
      std::vector<T_out> res( input.size() );

      for( size_t i = 0 ; i < input.size() ; ++i )
        res[ i ] = _f( input[ i ] );

      return res;
    }

  private:
    Func _f;
    // ...

};

template< typename Func >
A<Func> A_wrapper( Func f )
{
  return A<Func>( f );
}

int main()
{
  // example for f(x) = x*x
  std::vector<float> input = { /* ... */ };

  auto f          = []( float in ){ return in*in; };
  auto map_square = A_wrapper( f );

  auto res = map_square( input );

  return 0;
 }
```

Using `typename std::result_of<Func(T_in)>::type` instead of `std::result_of_t<Func(T_in)>` should work also for C++11, not only for C++14.